# Passing a cursor to a service

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a list view that could be potentially large (10k+ items).  When the user clicks on an item in the list, I take an action in a Service which needs the cursor for access to the entire list.  Since I cant pass the cursor through an Intent from the activity I just send the id of the selected item to the Service then requery the database based off of this id.  However, since this is a complex query with a lot of data, it can potentially take a while.  Would it be faster to have this cursor in a Parseable class instead of requerying the database?  I can then pass the parseable class in an Intent to the Activity.

Thanks

Comment: How is this Service related to your Activity? Do you expect them to both be running in the same process?

Comment: Yes, they will both be running in the same process.  Basically the Service accepts the cursor from the Activity and does some processing on the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cursor window to parcel data from a cursor.If you are not doing any write operations:

```
CursorWindow window = new CursorWindow("MY_CURSOR_WINDOW");

cursor.fillWindow(0, window);

intent.putExtra(String name, window);
```

In case you want to do write operation then you need to query and get a cursor,since cursorwindow caches the data and nothing else much.

### http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow.html

Cheers.

Comment: Does this iterate through the entire collection and serialize + deserialize the data when passing it?